# Formatting and displaying data in Vega chart legends

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I am trying to build a pie chart in vega lite where the legend has a formatted table-like structure, displaying the field name (Data N in example) and the data (40 etc. in screenshot) together.

Ideally this would also format appropriately when the Data field strings extend in value (essentially like table formatting)

[Mocked up image of desired output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2E0SK.png)

I have been playing with the labelExpr function as part of the legend variable; however there doesn't seem an easy way to get the values into the legend, nor does there seem to be any options around formatting it?

[My working example of the chart is here on vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AEEABBBoIcguIZw1LsJOsyGA7nRiHETOMtXLDypJhUiioBKKigxEiCDGpoANqgUAHkbOoAnmggAGI2gsoAjMGR0XBoACwADAC+ConJZKkZ6DlweQBMRVExaADMAGw1dZgp6ZkteT2dJWj51bUgScMNo825ymVT3agAnIML9Y1ja2Kbpahle4sjTdlrfaczVQC6NSDI6gDWmfZQwXCyUDYyhosjIaFA9DggXBIAAZmtMsVukpMGkcGcQABHBhIWQ6QI6UggV6AwSpGHw1rKTJXZYZFFojGyNgIEFRYIyBxoWFRCBwJQWMj-anhEAQNIIJhsQQAFUZmQg2PspQFSE8giyckwmX0miihgAcvZ1GwnMFBGrWpq8QBlGgALzO+QAHKr1QBRAAeOHUmUkbBBAAo4v5MAwEJQLeqFAByQwxhSh8OUJFwJ4ASmJVWzQA)

many thanks in advance!

```
{
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
    "description": "A simple pie chart with embedded data.",
    "data": {
        "values": [
            {
                "category": "Field1",
                "value": 40
            },
            {
                "category": "Field2",
                "value": 36
            },
            {
                "category": "Field3",
                "value": 10
            },
            {
                "category": "Field4",
                "value": 9
            },
            {
                "category": "Field5",
                "value": 4
            },
            {
                "category": "Field6",
                "value": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    "mark": "arc",
    "encoding": {
        "theta": {
            "field": "value",
            "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "color": {
            "field": "category",
            "type": "nominal",
            "sort": false,
            "legend": {
                "symbolType": "square",
                "labelFont": "Arial Narrow",
                "labelFontSize": 18,
                "labelExpr": "join([datum.label,' ',datum.value])"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That isn't really a legend in your mock up. If you wanted to create that, it would be a mini chart. You can search on here on how to create a table in Vega.

Comment: Thanks David - I did not know tables were fairly straight forward in Vega. Now just need to work out how to combine them with a chart and also incorporate the auto label colour correlation that Vega does in legends.

Comment: https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example solution in Vega (not Vega-Lite). Add a scale to lookup the data values:

```
 {
      "name": "scale_legend_values",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {"data": "data_table", "field": "category"},
      "range":  {"data": "data_table", "field": "amount"}
    }
```

and use that scale in the legend label text:

```
  "legends": [
    {
      "labelFont": "Arial Narrow",
      "labelFontSize": 18,
      "symbolType": "square",
      "fill": "color",
      "title": "category",
      "encode": {
        "labels": {
          "update": {"text": {"signal": "datum.label + ' ' + scale('scale_legend_values', datum.label)"}}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

[View in Vega on-line editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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-v++r0YB3JOsxAqYqeMhYZuV6gIYRoXLMEh3CAmjKAM2gAHJWGEth+FJLiGLJGwAMo0AAXq0SwABwyBAUwIEw94ACrPouACODBWPxzpRsC94+pSdCzixuJ+OalrWuW2kXEOIAMDgNTQSycAhncKYRmRf6YAwCCUOFhjaAA1NoADkhV5bo6G1gV7rGJh5A4XhCgFVInjeBlWXSYYLbISewpAA)

[image]

Complete Vega spec:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A simple pie chart with embedded data.",
  "background": "white",
  "padding": 5,
  "width": 200,
  "height": 200,
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "data_table",
      "values": [
        {"category": "Field1", "amount": 40},
        {"category": "Field2", "amount": 36},
        {"category": "Field3", "amount": 10},
        {"category": "Field4", "amount": 9},
        {"category": "Field5", "amount": 4},
        {"category": "Field6", "amount": 1}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "pie",
          "field": "amount"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "mark_arc",
      "type": "arc",
      "from": {"data": "data_table"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "category"},
          "x": {"signal": "width / 2"},
          "y": {"signal": "height / 2"},
          "outerRadius": {"signal": "min(width,height) / 2"},
          "innerRadius": {"value": 0},
          "startAngle": {"field": "startAngle"},
          "endAngle": {"field": "endAngle"}
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {"data": "data_table", "field": "category"},
      "range":  {"scheme": "category20"}
    },
    {
      "name": "scale_legend_values",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {"data": "data_table", "field": "category"},
      "range":  {"data": "data_table", "field": "amount"}
    }
  ],
  "legends": [
    {
      "labelFont": "Arial Narrow",
      "labelFontSize": 18,
      "symbolType": "square",
      "fill": "color",
      "title": "category",
      "encode": {
        "labels": {
          "update": {"text": {"signal": "datum.label + ' ' + scale('scale_legend_values', datum.label)"}}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```